# Malformed requests for each capybara/selenium 4 test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

After upgrading from selenium 3 to 4, every feature test triggers two invalid requests and puma logs the following error:

```
2024-02-06 09:38:36 -03 HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>
```

This is how the chromedriver is configured:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: [
      'headless=new',
      'no-sandbox',
      '--window-size=2560,1440',
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--allow-running-insecure-content',
      "--enable-logging", # Enables logging
      "--log-level=0", # Enables all logging
      "--v=1" # Sets the verbosity level of logging
    ]
  )

  options.add_option('goog:loggingPrefs', { browser: 'ALL' })

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
```

I can't identify which requests are these?
Any idea on how to get rid of them or how to debug these requests?

Comment: Newer versions of Selenium will be using "Chrome for testing" so likely it's not configured to default to non-https endpoints for the domain you're testing against. You probably previously configured your local Chrome to allow that.  By default non-configured Chrome instances will default to trying any url provided on https first, which is what the error would appear to be